# Using Con Statement in Raster Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, con

I am using ArcGIS Desktop version 10.7.0.10450

I have previously used Con statements in the Raster Calculator that now do not seem to work. I did hundreds of these with raster data about five years ago and have come back to updated the project but cannot figure out what has changed. The basics are a simple if/then statement:

```
new_raster=(Con(("raster1" - 100) < 0, 0, ("raster1"  -  100))) * 31
```

The result would be 0 if raster1-100 is less than zero or raster1-100. The multiplier at the end is a constant and could be done outside this statement if needed.

When I run the raster calculator it completes quickly, shows the following results, but there is no output raster and no error message.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Set environment extent, cell size to ones of raster. Con(raster<100, 0, raster-100)*31

Comment: Thanks FelixP ... the environment and cell sizes are set, but the result is the same. Nothing I do generates a result when this ran without a hiccup previously.

Comment: Try output to raster grid stored in folder. Databases sometimes do crazy things to raster.

Comment: After two reboots of the software and one reboot of the computer it worked! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I noticed the statement in your OP "... it completes quickly, ... but there is no output..."  I started noticing the same thing circa 10.6 or 10.7, both Arcmap and ArcCatalog.  If I run a tool and it completes quickly w/o results I know that Arc is hosed, and the only solution is to power cycle the computer.  Go figure...